# Update multiple workbook in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Is there any way to update multiple workbook at the same time?
In my case, i would like to update only in a workbook (master) and i would want other workbook to automatically be updated the same as i update the master.
Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible (and common actually).

You can make a link from one workbook to another. Changing the field in the master workbook will then give the option to update the other workbooks.

**How does it work?**
You open 2 (or more workbooks) that you want to link. In the master sheet(s) you enter the numbers/text as you normally would. It can also be a formula that gets its calculations from other fields, such as a sum from 2 or more fields.

In the slave sheet(s) you first type an `=` and then select the cell in the master sheet, followed by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The formula it generates will have all the necessary bits to reference the other worksheet. Do note, if you move the master sheet(s) to a different location, it will break this link.

Once done, you can close both documents and safe the changes to the slave sheet(s). If you now reopen a slave sheet, it will tell you there's a link to another worksheet. It will ask you if you want to update the values or not. If you do, it will automatically open that sheet, first, copy the values over and close the document again. For this action, it will open the master sheet in read-only mode, so someone else can be editing the file without this causing for problems.

But only after they saved their sheet, will reopening the slave sheet(s) get the new values.

**Common usage**
This is commonly used to create reports for many employees. Each employee gets a master sheet. They fill in their numbers. All these sheets are linked to a slave sheet that blindly copies these values into one document and puts the values neatly next to each other.

Comment: what if the master sheet happened to be in a different location? different location means different file isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thats perfectly fine, as long as you can have both workbooks open at the same time. So if a user does not have access to both locations, then it will throw in a "I can't find the worksheet. Please browse to it" when you attempt to update it. If you have access to both files, it doesn't really matter where the documents are located. It can be that the master sheets are on a networkshare, and the slave is on your local computer.

Comment: Also, technically speaking, the master and slave roles are reversed here. Slave is to serve the numbers, master is to collect them. But I used your terminology to keep it understandable for you.

Comment: thank you so much! truth to be told i am so noob in this stuff so can i get back to you if i cant seem to understand anything?

Comment: Sure. Even better, ask a new question and me, or someone else will answer your question for you.

Comment: what if for example i have 2 different workbook (PR Record & Service/Maintenance Record) and in the PR Record i have three sheets (Service, New Equipment, Spare Parts). My question is how can i update the Service/Maintenance Record by only updating the PR Record? And i only want the update happen to Service/Maintenance Record if i update the Service sheet on PR Record?

Can anyone help Pleasee.

Comment: The technique is exactly the same as described in my answer. Open both workbooks, go to the cell that you want to start a link with, type = then click on the cell that it should link to in the other workbook. So, open Service/Maintenance Record workbook, select the correct sheet, then the correct cell and type =. Now go to the PR Record, select sheet Service, then click on the cell it should link to. Notice it will have a border around it. Press enter or the check mark in the formule bar to confirm this formula, and they are now linked.